# Is this method of finding a "dual curve" correct?

Tags: projective-geometry, plane-curves, curves, projective-space, duality-theorems

I have a very limited exposure to projective geometry, but I'm having fun exploring the concept of duality. In particular I'd like to know if this naive method of finding a "dual" curve to a given curve $\Gamma$ (in the real projective plane) could be correct. Here's the idea.
Let $P(t)$ be a point of $\Gamma$ with (homogeneous) coordinates $(a(t),b(t),1)$, and let $P_t^*$ be the line dual to $P$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
P_t^*:\qquad a(t)x+b(t)y+1=0
\end{equation}
Now, and this is where problems could arise, I'd like to assume that the set
\begin{equation}
P^*=\{ a(t)x+b(t)y+1=0\quad|\quad t\in\mathbb{R}\}
\end{equation}
is the set of tangents to the dual curve $\Gamma^*$.
In this case, I could find the equation for $\Gamma^*$ by considering the following limit:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}P_t^*\cap P_{t+h}^*
\end{equation}
My question is: is this method plausible or is it complete nonsense? I have checked it only for the case of a parabola $\Gamma$ given by $P(t)=(t,at^2,1)$, which yields a "dual" parabola $\Gamma^*$ given by $P(t)=(t,\frac{t^2}{4a},1)$.

I am afraid that the assumption of $P^*$ being a set of tangents is way too strong and basically unmotivated. If it's the case, is there an elementary method of obtaining a dual curve from a given one?

Comment: * sits on a rock and waits *

Comment: * bounties to the sharks *

Comment: Is my answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general notes on finding the envelope of a family of curves (in this case the curves are tangents) are on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)).  The approach sounds much like what you propose.

There is another article specifically on [dual curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve).  They take the approach of calculating tangents on the original curve and then finding the point duals of these tangents to compute the dual curve.

So your method is definitely plausible.